# Restoring Visitor IPs in WHMCS with Cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, ip, cloudflare, whmcs

**Hello,**

So i have a wordpress-based website and within it, the WHMCS 7.1.2 core installation.

The issue is that when a clients purchases a product within the WHMCS cart, the purchase is logged with Cloudflare server's ip instead of the client's real ip adress. **I want it to show the real ip at least inside WHMCS.**

Pretty much whenever anybody visits my website and its sub-domains, their real ip is masked and replaced with Cloudflare's.

I've found that it is possible to reverse the ip by using this php code:

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
?>
```

But i don't know how to add it to WHMCS or if there's any other way to reverse the ip?

I would really appreciate if anybody could please guide me on how to do this.

**Regards.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHMCS has settings for such service, called Trusted Proxies, check documentation for [Trusted Proxy Settings](https://docs.whmcs.com/Trusted_Proxy_Settings)

Basically, from Setup > General Settings > Security Tab:

1. Set `Proxy IP Header` to X_FORWARDED_FOR
2. Add IP address to `Trusted Proxies`. This is the tricky part, since you need to add [CloudFlare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)